# Why is this question closed?

Tags: discussion

Ok.

This question is totally ok to be opened, and it also has too many possible answers. - > [Building a New Website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5067/building-a-new-website?rq=1)

I asked a question about approaching to build 18+ page -> [Is warning users on the homepage enough to limit access to 18+ for a website with adult content on it?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/87394/approach-for-building-intro-to-18-website)

And it is on hold because it's too broad. I don't think that it's too broad and there's no answer and/or question on that matter in our community.

Why is that so? I don't think that it's too broad. If you guys think that it is, I'll edit it again.

Thanks.

Comment: It often is a matter of experience or imagination or point of view. There can also be other factors, however, we are all human and not any one of us will see things exactly the same way. One question that was marked as being too broad I petitioned to be re-opened in the comments stating that I could answer the question factually and simply without ambiguity. It was re-opened and answered. You ask a fair question. If you can, can you help the moderator see the scope in the question so that it does not appear to be too broad?? BTW- I like your answers! I am glad you are here. Cheers!!

Comment: Hah, tnx :) well, I edited the question so it doesn't appear too broad. I'm interested in angle of approach, and there's no question on that matter on webmasters. I'm glad you like my answers :)

Comment: @JohnConde srsly, can you explain me this a little bit? I'd like this question to be active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Building a New Website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5067/building-a-new-website?rq=1) is a question from 2010.   There are several questions from early in this site's history that in hindsight were a mistake to leave open.   I have now locked it because

> This question exists because it has historical significance, **but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site**, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: [help center](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help).

Questions asking for the "best approach" for something don't end up working well on this site.  Multiple different but all "correct" answers get written but only one can be accepted.   This means that other people tend to use the voting to push their favorite answer to the top and may even downvote good answers that they don't prefer.  It ends up not playing well with the voting and point system.

Comment: I know what to do, I've stated that I think that it's in best way to do a html entry page to the site itself. I've edited the question too so it doesn't become too broad. I'd like you to review that question again or advise me to edit it so it can be reopened.

Comment: i just putted that question because it was first on the right.

Comment: thanks for the edit mate :)

Comment: I've helped you edit the question further to a point that it can be reopened.

Comment: I welcome that. Thank you once again.